# How to add iframe content to main page?

Tags: javascript, html

Actually i have iframe which has some important content in it ,but problem is that how can i have add content to my page in which that iframe resides.
Thanks

Comment: check the link posted in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get content of iframe by using following function, than you can add content in main page html.

```
function getContentFromIframe(iFrameName)
{

    var myIFrame = document.getElementById(iFrameName);
    var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;

    //Do whatever you need with the content    

}
```

check for more detail : http://www.roseindia.net/java/pass-value-example/pass-value-from-iframe-parent.shtml

Comment: but how to get the values of iframe

Comment: by innerHTML you can able to access content of frame what else you want

Comment: atually what i want is that if i click any image inside iframe it will generate value and by catching that value i would be able to do some another task.
this is what i want...
Please respond as quick as possible
Thanks

Comment: check this might help you : http://www.roseindia.net/java/pass-value-example/pass-value-from-iframe-parent.shtml