# How to create iframe about:blank without src but content html javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to create a iframe without src ( about:blank ) but that iframe content some javascript html

I need to do it because I don't want create a hosted webpages on server for this mission, this will make more connection to server which are no good for resource. And also don't want to write direct javascript html on webpage because they make the webpage load slow most time when load/running.

How to do it by using javascript (jquery maybe )?

iframe eg :

```
<iframe src="about:blank" width="300" height="250" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" ></iframe>
```

and its content:

```
<div>xxx</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var abc=1 </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://1234.net/js.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for some answered following. 
But I need to clarify that script will create iframe by javascript also, because the need to create iframes in one page with different ids.
Please look at my test:
http://jsfiddle.net/rDkEw/

The problems are:
if use **document.body.appendChild**, the iframe will create on body of webpage, but I need it to keep it inside the current div which hold the JavaScript.

Comment: Does this work? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rDkEw/13/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$('#myIframe').appendTo('#iframeDiv');
```

your iframe id = "myIframe"

your html content div id = "iframeDiv";

note: without jQuery, the two other answers seem perfectly suited.

Answer (score 12):

**For everyone googling this after 2016:** Use a  [data: URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), URLs prefixed with the data: scheme, allow content creators to embed small files inline in documents.

```
<iframe src="data:text/html, <h1>Your HTML</h1>"></iframe>
```

Comment: HTML data-urls are currently NOT supported by Edge.

Comment: Now [99.76%](https://caniuse.com/?search=Data%20URLs) browser coverage, including Edge.

Answer (score 4):

An `<iframe>` has a `contentDocument` property representing its… content’s document. You can use `write()` on that. [Here’s a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/B2QRE/)

Comment: thanks for help, could you have look ad my updated post, which i need to create iframe by javascript also and need put some iframe on one page and it must inside one div .. not direct on body

Comment: @BinhNguyen: That’s not a problem with adding content to the `<iframe>`, then, is it? You just need to append the element itself to something other than `document.body`. So instead of `document.body.appendChild`, find your `<div>` and call `appendChild` on that.

Comment: Might not of answered the question the way OP wanted, but helped me all the same :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeid');

var div_el = document.createElement('div');
div_el.innerHTML = "....";
iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(div_el);
```

A jQuery solution:

```
$('#iframeid').contents().find('body').append("<div>.....</div>");
```

Comment: thanks for help, could you have look ad my updated post, which i need to create iframe by javascript also and need put some iframe on one page and it must inside one div .. not direct on body

Answer (score 0):

You can add any content to page in iframe as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035492/how-to-add-iframe-content-to-main-page) but as you don't have a page loaded I doubt the javascript you add to this page will work. You can give it a try.